# ruby on rails how to input text into a website after using Nokogiri to open it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I'm writing a unit test for our app for the forget password mutation. The mutation will send the email with the new randomly generated password to the provided email address, and I want to test this. Right now I'm using this to access yopmail.com

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://yopmail.com/en/"))

puts doc.to_html
```

On yopmail.com, there's an input box where u input the disposable email to get to the inbox, I just want to know how I would input the disposable email that I generated in my code into yopmail using Nokogiri or whatever other means. Sorry if the explanation isn't clear, I'm not sure how to make this completely make sense. Thank you.

Comment: Nokogiri is just used to read, not fill out input fields. In this case you should write a Selenium test instead. You can for example use Cucumber to write your scenario or other JS frameworks.

In short these framework allows you to open and test webpages

Answer (score 0):

As TTD already mentioned, Nokogiri can only parse HTML / XML but you can't really control the input (although you can alter the HTML itself but that doesn't help for your problem).

What I would do is to avoid entering user input as it will also make your tests a lot more flaky. You can get your mailbox for instance with `https://yopmail.com/?<name-of-your-inbox>` so you don't have to enter any input.

Unfortunately, yopmail seems to not offer any API. If you're not bound to yopmail, you could for instance try https://rapidapi.com/Privatix/api/temp-mail which offers an API and it make it easier to parse the email results.